# List images from a directory depending the uploaded date

Tags: php, glob

I have a piece of code that print images from a directory.

```
<?
$directory = 'assets/images/';
$files = glob($directory."*.{jpg}", GLOB_BRACE);
$filecount = count($files);

for($i=1; $i<=$filecount; $i++) {
    echo '<img src="'.$file.'" class="img-responsive">';
}
?>
```

It's working perfectly.

Except that I want to display my image depending the uploaded date.

Is it possible please ?

Thanks.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function listdir_by_date($path){
    $dir = opendir($path);
    $list = array();
    while($file = readdir($dir)){
        if ($file != '.' and $file != '..'){
            // add the filename, to be sure not to
            // overwrite a array key
            $ctime = filectime($data_path . $file) . ',' . $file;
            $list[$ctime] = $file;
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
    krsort($list);
    return $list;
}
```

[Reference](http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/php/listdir-by-date.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Okie, give this a go, using your `glob` method:

```
$directory = 'assets/images/';

$images = [];
$files = glob($directory . '*.{jpg}', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($files as $file) {
    $images[] = [filectime($file), $file];
}

array_multisort($images, SORT_DESC);

foreach ($images as $image) {
    echo '<img src="' . $image[1] . '" class="img-responsive"><br>';
}
```

Just a slightly different method then what @mayank-pandey presented, but same basic end results.